# extract json with nodered

Tags: json, node-red

I want to extract json part in a message with node red

I receive the message in node red but I can't extract the data
exemple of a message:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1

Host: xxx.xx.xxx.5:9000

User-Agent: libcurl-agent/1.0

Content-type: application/json

Accept: application/json

Content-Length: 526   
   {
   "timestamp": 1571997083,
   "data": {
      "temperature": 20.613545532227,
      "humidity": 61.3828125,
      "battery": 3.47
   },
   "frame": "814962xxxx16a1dc5",
   "gatewayID": "AA555Axxxx0xx964",
   "othersGW": [],
   "clientID": "xxxx",
   "DevAddr": "011xxxxb",
   "DevEUI": "8cf9xxx000000xxx",
   "sensorInstallId": "8cf95xxx0000xxxx",
   "loraPort": 8,
   "fcnt": 1607,
   "rxpk": {
      "tmst": 2380181019,
      "time": "2019-10-25T09:51:23.472998Z",
      "chan": 0,
      "rfch": 0,
      "freq": 867.1,
      "stat": 1,
      "modu": "LORA",
      "datr": "SF7BW125",
      "codr": "4/5",
      "lsnr": 9,
      "rssi": -72,
      "size": 22,
      "data": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/YxWg=="
   }
}
```

so I would like to have data of temperature etc...
and I don't know the node I have to use

Thanks a lot

Comment: The `http-request` node should return just JSON response as `msg.payload` when it returns. Or are you wanting to know how to extract just one field e.g. the temperature from that object?

Comment: wanting to know how to extract just one field... yes  the problem is the beginning of the message before {......}

Comment: Please edit the question to give more information about where that message is coming from. It looks like you are using `curl` rather than the built in tools to make a http request

Comment: I use the input node" tcp " to listen the port and I receive the message / and in this message and I would like to extract temperature ....

Answer (score 1):

Having got a better view of what you are trying to do from the comments.

Using the `TCP-in` node is probably not the right approach for this. You will do much better using the `HTTP-in`/`HTTP-out` nodes as these will handle dealing with all the HTTP-header and sending a proper response to the client so the connection gets closed.

The `HTTP-in` node takes a path e.g. `/input` which will be appended to the Node-RED URL giving something like `http://localhost:1880/input`. It also takes a HTTP verb which in this case would be `POST`. You can find more details and lots of examples in the Node-RED cookbook [here](https://cookbook.nodered.org/#http-endpoints).

You will need to update the client to point to the correct path and port.

Comment: Thanks ...I want to recover a json message send to me by a server and I dont know to do this .... when iI listen the port tcp 9000 (eg) I have the message ..... wiith "http in" no

Comment: As I said, you will need to change the other end as well. Trying to do your own HTTP with the tcp-in node is a REALLY bad idea.

Comment: @chris35 if you need more help, you will do better asking on the Node-RED Slack channel or the forum (link to here when you do so people can see the context)

Answer (score 0):

You will need JSON node to convert the message string into an object.

Nodered has a very good documentation and hands on examples.
See below for some help:

- [This is great example how to to use the json node](https://cookbook.nodered.org/basic/convert-json)
- [This
  describes how to work with JSON data](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/messages#working-with-json)

Comment: The `http-request` node should do that for you, no need for the `JSON` node unless the content-type from the server is wrong (which we can see it hasn't)