# How can I recover a json message from a distant server?

Tags: node-red

I would like to recover a JSON message in node-red from a distant server

I've tried with a node `tcp-in` but it's not a good solution because I don't have only the JSON....

what's the node better for me ?

Comment: Please do as I asked for your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58558447/extract-json-with-nodered) and ask on the Node-RED forum or Slack channel where we can full explore the problem you are trying to solve. There is no where near enough information for anybody to be able to help properly.

Answer (score 0):

The best option for you is to use a HTTP request node, you can retrieve the complete Json in the payload or you can parse it like below :

[image]